# Aurelia i18n HTML attributes with namespace

Tags: i18next, aurelia

How is it possible to select the proper namespace when translating html attributes? The default syntax is like:

`<span i18n="home.title">Title</span>`

For instance, in the view model the approach is the following:

`this.i18n.tr('invalidName', {ns: 'errors'})`

I'm using version 0.5.3 of `aurelia-i18n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best options I would suggest are:

```
<span t="errors:invalidName"></span>
<span t="invalidName" t-params.bind="{ns: 'errors'}"></span>
<span>${'errors:invalidName' | t & signal:'aurelia-translation-signal}</span>
<span>${'invalidName' | t:{ns: 'errors'} & signal:'aurelia-translation-signal}</span>
```